# Nginx: What is this figure in error log mean ? *26924830

Tags: nginx

I found this message in error log. I know what this whole error message means, but I couldn't find the information about '*26924830'.

error message below.

`00 [warn] 3051#0: *26924830 a client request body is buffered to a temporary file /var/lib/nginx/tmp/client_body/`

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26125951/187292) contains an explanation of the nginx error log format, according to that you're looking at the connection id, which is ephemeral and probably only useful for correlating with other log messages.